# Calling R script from JSP

Tags: r, jsp

I am stuck with embedding R script in JSP. Can someone please help me how to call R script from JSP?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is a tad broad. Can you expand your question to pin point the exact problem you're having?

Comment: @Roman Luštrik Thank you for response, I have data in mongoDB and trying to extract data and display through JSP. Now for the same data I have to generate a graph which I am doing through my R code.
Now What I want is on click of some button from my JSP, i want to call this R script which generates the graph. I am stuck with this problem. Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance